# Meteor MongoDB: $pull/$pullAll error

Tags: mongodb, meteor

So I'm trying to write an event handler and method that adds the username of a post and adds it to the array `following` under the Meteor user's `profile` document. If it's already there, it removes the name from the user's `following` array, unfollowing the user.

The event handler calls userFollow method that checks for already following and all that. That stuff all works. What doesn't work is the actual MongoDB functions. Something in the query below throws `Exception while invoking method 'userFollow' MongoError: Cannot apply $pull/$pullAll modifier to non-array`. I know for a fact that the under the users collection, `user>profile>following` is an array of usernames.

Why am I getting this error with this query?

```
userFollow: function(postAttributes) {
    var user = Meteor.user();
    var targetUser = postAttributes.username;

/* Check if the user is logged in, then check
*  if the user is tying to follow themself. */
if (!user) {
    throw new Meteor.Error(401, "You need to login to follow.");
}
    if (user.username == targetUser) {
        throw new Meteor.Error(401, "You can can't follow yourself.");
    }

    /* Checks if the target user is already in the
    *  current user's following array. */
    function userFollowed(targetUser, user) {
        for (var i in user.profile.following) {
            if (user.profile.following[i] == targetUser) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /* Uses userFollowed to either follow or unfollow
    *  the user in question. */
    if (userFollowed(targetUser, user) == true ) {
        console.log("Unfollowing");

        Meteor.users.update(
            { _id: user._id },
            { $pull: { profile: { following: targetUser } } },
            { multi: true }
        );

    } else if (userFollowed(targetUser, user) == false ) {
        console.log("Following");
        Meteor.users.update(
            { _id: user._id },
            { $push: { profile: { following: targetUser } } }
        );
    } else {
        throw new Meteor.Error(401, "The userFollowed check failed.");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the syntax should be:

```
{$push: {'profile.following': targetUser}}
```

However, you may want to use [$addToSet](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) instead:

```
{$addToSet: {'profile.following': targetUser}}
```

That will ensure you only ever have unique values in the `following` array. I realize you are checking for this with `userFollowed`, but it's a good pattern to use anyway.

Note also that you can replace `userFollowed` with this:

```js
var userFollowed = _.contains(user.profile.following, targetUser);
```